# GAE writing information to datastore is causing duplicate writes

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have an app which holds a quiz every weekend. Basically I send questions to my users using GCM and they can reply by selecting the correct answer option in the app. These answers are then stored in the datastore in the form of entities.

I have a function to write the phone number and answer (correct/incorrect )to the datastore -

```
  public static void SaveQuizAnswers(String phoneNumberSave, String Answer){
      Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
        try {
          Entity entity = new Entity(QUIZ);
          entity.setProperty(PHONE_NO, phoneNumberSave);
          entity.setProperty(ANSWER, Answer);
          datastore.put(entity);
          txn.commit();
        } finally {
          if (txn.isActive()) {
            txn.rollback();
          }
        }     
  }
```

This function is called by the code below -

```
String Answer = req.getParameter("Answer");
String phoneNumberSave = req.getParameter("phoneNumber");
Datastore.SaveQuizAnswers(phoneNumberSave, Answer);
```

The issue is that I can see multiple responses written for the same user. I have tried making `<threadsafe>false</threadsafe>` so that App engine ensures single requests being served by an instance but I still see duplicates. So, for example if I have sent 5 questions to multiple users, then for every user there should not be more than 5 responses, but this is not the case and I see 7 or 8 responses per user. What is causing this? I have checked the app and the code is fine there. Is there any modification required in the above code. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you need to do the `put` function in transaction, you need to pass the `txn` object in the `put()` method.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#put(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Transaction,%20com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity)

Comment: if I use txn in put(txn, entity), then how is it different from the other put(entity). Doc says "executes within the provided transaction" but I am not sure. Will this stop duplicate writes?

Answer (score 0):

You create a new entity every time with an auto-generated identifier. If the same user submits a response multiple times, you will see multiple entities.

The only way to prevent it is to check if this response already exists, and override it.

Another option is to make response entities child entities of a quiz entity, and use a phone number as a name for each response entity. Then you don't have to make any checks - you can construct a new entity with a phone number as an identifier, and if such entity already exists it would be overwritten.

NB: As a side note, there is no point in using a transaction in your example - it makes no difference.

Comment: You can also build the entity keys yourself based on phone and quiz+question numbers. Then you wont have dups and no need for child entities (slower)

Comment: @ZigMandel: You are right, but child entities are not slower. In fact, ancestor queries are often faster.

Comment: Yes they are ro commit. You can commit at a rate of 1 per second.

Comment: To elaborate the issue, if I send 5 questions to my users then when they reply, I want to save all 5 responses separately in the form of entities (not overwrite). The code does the same thing and is working fine except for some cases I can see there are more than 5 entities written for some users. Am not sure what is causing this. Also users can reply only once to each question so there should not be more than 5 answers for each users.

Comment: The solutions we are suggesting would save 5 separate responses, but they would prevent a duplicate response from the same student to the same question. How do you ensure "can reply only once"? Can they hit a back button, double click on a submit button, etc.? Is it possible that you attach more than one handler to a button? Is it possible that your response fails to reach the client and so the client thinks it needs to submit it again?

Comment: Coming back after a long time but the issue still persists. I have ensured in my code that once the user submits an answer then the button is disabled so there is no question of submitting multiple answers for a single question. Also, hitting back will close the activity and they cannot go back and answer again. Not user what else can be wrong with the code.

Comment: Another thought is, if multiple users submits answers at the same time, will the server code mentioned above in the function misbehave? Do I have to take any other precaution? I have tried Threadsafe as false but still I see multiple entries? Should I try to synchronize (SaveQuizAnswers) the function so that answers are recorded one at a time?

Comment: Threads have no impact on this code, and there is nothing wrong with it. You must have a problem somewhere else. Why don't you just debug the process of submitting a response? See what values you pass the first time, then the second time, and compare.